# Built-in microphone not detected after installing Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: microphone, amd-ryzen, 23.10

For some reason the microphone isn't recognized. It was working without problems in Ubuntu 23.04. I'm using a Lenovo YOGA 7 14ARB7 (AMD Ryzen 6800U) and I was positively surprised that the speakers were working right away with Ubuntu 23.10, since I still had to do some fixes in 23.04. 
I checked several other articles now and they were dealing with older models or Ubuntu versions... The microphone worked without any issues on Ubuntu 23.04.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and I found a workaround to make microphone work.
You can read this thread on french ubuntu forum :
https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=2081994

Simple process :

1/ Get kernel 6.6 (https://www.kernel.org/)

2/Compile et install kernel 6.6 as dscribed : https://davidaugustat.com/linux/how-to-compile-linux-kernel-on-ubuntu

Actually, I have no explanation why it works, but it works :-D

Hope it will help you.

Comment: One of your links is broken. Can you please edit your post and replace it. Also it is a better if you include the important parts in your post.

Comment: Links are OK now, hope it will help

Comment: Thank you so much! I just installed the Linux 6.6.0-060600rc5-generic kernel with the mainline installer and now it recognizes the microphone again! maybe they messed up some things for our units in the 6.5 kernel? 
The rc1 version didn't fix the mic, but rc5 id luckily :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem also occurred after updating from 23.04 to 23.10.
After trying many solutions online that were not working, I attempted to use GPT4 to help me solve the issue.

Eventually, I executed `sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio`.

Afterwards, the system recommended me to install two other packages to replace these two, they seemed to be pipewire-pulse and pipewire-alsa. After restarting the system, my built-in audio device was back to normal.

I'm not sure what effects this might have, it could potentially impact software that uses pulseaudio to process audio. If other solutions don't work for you, you can try this one.