# Auxiliary Headset microphone not detected in Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: sound, alsa, microphone, headset

I was dual booting Ubuntu 22.04.4 and Windows 11 on my Acer Nitro 5 (RTX 4050). When I installed discord on Ubuntu I noticed my headset (Steelseries Arctis 1) microphone was not detected/working properly.

In my system sound settings two input devices are displayed: Digital Microphone (webcam mic, works fine) and Headphones Stereo Microphone. I am not sure if the latter input device reflects my headset mic being detected on Ubuntu due to the fact that my Output device "Headphones" populates and un-populates in the audio settings when it is plugged/unplugged. the "Headphones Stereo Microphone does not.

I have attempted a few solutions:

1. [Jack Retasking](https://askubuntu.com/a/1163677/980324)
2. [Troubleshooting in pavucontrol](https://askubuntu.com/a/19523/42073)
3. [Reloading pulseaudio](https://askubuntu.com/a/508234/1773508)

I then resorted to upgrading to Ubuntu 23.10 as users stated it solved some of these audio issues, however once I realized the microphone was still not functioning I opted to [upgrade to Kernel 6.6](https://askubuntu.com/a/1491600/1773508)

Currently I am dual booting Ubuntu 23.10 and Windows 11. The headset still functions properly within Windows 11, but is not detected/not functioning properly in Ubuntu. Any insight as to what could be causing this/ ANY solution to this would be a great help as I would like to use Linux as my primary OS, only utilizing windows for occasional gaming.